# Determination of Quote / Trade Ratio

Tags: market-data, high-frequency, market-microstructure

What is the common criteria used to count a quote or trade in reference to the quote/trade ratio?

**Criteria:**

- If it beats the best bid or offer.
- If it adds size to the best bid or offer.
- What if the best bid or offer is removed?  Does this count or not?

There may be some other criteria I am missing - please do include them if you find one.

Answer (score 1):

First define a **quote**: this is the bid and ask (price and volume). when any of them 4 change, it is said the quote changed. We all know what a trade is (nevertheless note if you send a liquidity consuming order of 100 on a queue made of 50+20+30, it generates 3 trades).

You can play with statistics (like order-to-trade ratio, not quote-to-trade), on te [SEC's MIDAS web site](http://www.sec.gov/marketstructure/datavis/ma_overview.html#.VQdQmRCG-YU):

[image]

Here is an example of QoT ratio over one day from the [NANEX web site](http://www.nanex.net/research/MsgRates/EquityMessageRates.html):

[image]

For more on all these indicators and their meaning, have a look at [Market Microstructure in Practice](http://www.worldscientific.com/worldscibooks/10.1142/8967).

Comment: your definition of a quote is different from his.